# Compare resources on two different unix servers

Tags: unix, server

I want to compare resources on two unix server which mainly determines the performance of a server . The parameter would be for e.g Memory ( free, swapped etc) , disk space, 
Number of cores and any other thing that can be considered . I don't want to 
compare performance of two server with running process using top etc ? 
I just want to compare the two servers in terms of resources available with them . `What are the parameters is should consider` and `where can i look for them` ? 
Note that the `workload on two servers are completely identical` and also any process say run on thread are also run by same number of threads. What i am looking for is basic parameters that i should compare and where to find them ?

Comment: To what end do you need this comparison?

Comment: I am confused why close flag is being hit here , what i want to know is to look for basic characteristic of  server i should look for in case two servers perform all the task with are identical . They are replica of each other  except the resources between them .

Comment: This might offer some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid when it comes to performance questions, the answer is "it depends". There isn't really any such thing as a direct performance comparison between two servers, because it's highly dependent on workload.

Each workload exhibits certain performance characteristics, and there will be one that hits a limiting factor first. It depends entirely on what that workload is doing, and the tradeoffs made in the code as to how it scales in terms of cpu-time, memory occupancy, disk IO, etc.

So it's basically impossible to say for sure, without bench marking your *specific* task on each system under differing workloads contention levels. There will be a nonlinear result in terms of adding load vs. completion times in all but the most trivial examples.

Comment: I see when two servers have similar process running on them just to be a backup copy for each other, In that case the ability of the two server can be quickly determined by a top command , which would give you RAM, SWAP ,CACHE memory available . But as you said this is a hard one without bench marking on specific task.